# Will python recalculate my string? if any(name in foo.string for name in names):

Tags: python-3.4

I wanted to update the following code:

```
foo_string=foo.string
for name in faa.names:
    if name in foo_string:
```

to:

```
if any(name in foo.string for name in faa.names):
```

But I wanted to get sure that `foo.string` would not be recalculated over each iteration.

I took a look to the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) and It says that this is the equivalent:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

But it doesn't helps me too much and I couln't find the C code. Also,
will `faa.names` be asked multiple times? or the list is stocked in memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I think `foo.string` will calulate each time until iteration satisfies `True`. So you can do this

```
foo_string=foo.string
if any(name in foo_string for name in faa.names):
```

Comment: Does it also happens when doing: `names_list=[name.lower() for name in faa.names]` ? is `faa.names` called multiple times?  I hope not!

Comment: Nop, here `name.lower()` will only execute in each iteration.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. (If there is any guide/article about this you may know please don't hesitate to post it, I'm really interested about knowing this kind of stuff!)